# Aws routing table - Static routing

Tags: routing, router, amazon-vpc

Amidst configuration of AWS routing table, AWS console allow static routing only.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html),

every VPC has an implicit router.

Assuming there is a public and private subnet configured within VPC. Public subnet  has its own routing table. Private subnet has its own routing table.

---

1) In AWS VPC, does each routing table resides in its own router? Multiple...

2) To populate routing tables, why AWS VPC allows only static routing? But not dynamic routing..

Comment: Dynamic routing to *where?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) In AWS VPC, does each routing table resides in its own router?

Essentially, Yes.  You can think of a routing table as a virtual router.

> 2) To populate routing tables, why AWS VPC allows only static routing?
>   But not dynamic routing.

You'll have to ask AWS why, but routing protocols are much more complicated than static routing, and it's rarely needed.

Answer (score 0):

AWS does allow dynamic route tables using BGP. You can read about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/adminguide/GenericConfig.html).